Conda commands are broken within Conda environment
After creating a fresh install of Miniconda from the website and running conda init inside of Anaconda Prompt, the (Base) environment in a new PowerShell window will run fine and I can install packages, create environments, etc. However, once I create an environment and activate it, running any subsequent conda commands are broken.
Every command I try to run gives me this response:
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-v] [--no-plugins] [-V] COMMAND ...
conda-script.py: error: argument COMMAND: invalid choice: '' (choose from 'activate', 'clean', 'commands', 'compare', 'config', 'create', 'deactivate', 'env', 'export', 'info', 'init', 'install', 'list', 'notices', 'package', 'content-trust', 'doctor', 'repoquery', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'rename', 'run', 'search', 'update', 'upgrade')

Base working and then CS439 env not
However, if I do this through the Anaconda Prompt executable then everything works fine:
Conda commands working
I've tried fully reinstalling and rebooting. The regular Anaconda install gives me the same problem. Not sure what to do from here.

It looks like the contents of your profile.ps1 file got messed up by the conda init command.  can you find C:\users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 or C:\users\username\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 and post the contents?
